# Removing a lists from a list of list, and more in Ocaml

Tags: arrays, list, ocaml

I have something like: `[[x,y,z],[a,b,c],[x,b,c],[!x,a,o]]` (list of lists)

And I want to remove all the Lists that have an element I search, for example, if I search for `x` I would have to have something like, `[[a,b,c],[!x,a,o]]`.

I know that if it was a simple List I would have to do something like: 
`let funfilter elem l = List.filter (fun x -> x != elem) l;;`
And for a List of List I need to do a filter inside a filter or a `map` `filter`. but I cant find the correct syntax for it, and I am not sure if it is the only thing I need to do to remove the Lists.

Other parallel question, if I want to remove only he element inside the List of List in this case the element `!x` -> results `[[a,b,c],[a,o]]`, how is it supposed me to do it?

I have a vague idea that is something with `Lis.filter` of a `List.filter` and/or `List.map` of a `List.filter`

-------------------EDIT-------------------------
As i said in a comment i did a function called head to return the 1º element it sees on a list like this

```
let head = 
function 
x::_ -> x
| _ -> failwith "no head?";;
```

and this function:

```
let funfilter elem ll = 
List.filter (fun inner -> (List.exists (fun x -> x <> elem) inner)) ll;;
```

(my list of list is called **passalista**)
Then I just did **`funfilter (head(head passalista)) passalista`**
Next to it I printed my *passalista* and the values were all them same.

What i am doing wrong now? :s
I need to clarify something to make the question easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`List.mem`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html):

```
let funfilter elem xs = 
  List.filter (fun inner -> not (List.mem elem inner)) xs
```

where `elem` is the element you want to use for filtering and `xs` is a list of lists.

Example:

```
# let funfilter elem xs = 
    List.filter (fun inner -> not (List.mem elem inner)) xs;;
val funfilter : 'a -> 'a list list -> 'a list list = <fun>
# let passalista = [[1; 2]; [3; 2; 1]; [4]];;
val passalista : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 2; 1]; [4]]
# funfilter (List.hd (List.hd passalista)) passalista;;
- : int list list = [[4]]
```

**Update**: replaced `List.exists` with `List.mem` as suggested by Anton Trunov.

Comment: I guess it didnt worked I did something like this: I defined a function called head to return the 1º element it sees let head = 
function 
x::_ -> x
| _ -> failwith "no head?";; then i did a function similar to the function you suggested to me let funfilter elem ll = 
  List.filter (fun inner -> (List.exists (fun x -> x <> elem) inner)) ll;;  and then I did a call of this  like this funfilter (head(head passalista)) passalista;; (passalista is the list of list)  and it is not filtering anything when i print passalista again it have the same value that had before. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You could use `fun inner -> not (List.mem elem inner)` as the lambda for `List.filter`

Comment: Joao Saraiva, please check out the example above, does it match what you're trying to do? Anton Trunov, good point! I've updated the code to use `List.mem`.

Comment: Ok I just tested it and it match **exactly** with what I wanted, Thanks!! Now I just need to discover how to remove only 1 variable inside a List of lists, maybe your function will help me to do it as well, again Thanks